# What's the Rails way to save an object with associatons?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a couple of classes with a usual one-to-many relationship, like:

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :blog
  validates :blog_id, presence: true
end
```

when I build a blog and add to it a bunch of posts:

```
blog = Blog.new
blog.posts = [Post.new, Post.new]
```

I cannot just save the blog, like this:

```
blog.save
```

because blog_id in the posts is blank, so validation for the posts are failing. I thought Rails was *smart* enough to either check the id or the presence of the object, but it isn't.

What's the proper Rails way to solve this? Something better than:

```
saved = true
Blog.transaction do
  saved &&= @blog.save
  if saved && params[:blog][:posts].responds_to?(:each)
    params[:blog][:posts].each do |post|
      p = Post.new({blog: @blog}, without_protection: true)
      saved &&= p.save
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it two ways

```
blog.posts.create(attributes_of_new_post)
```

or

```
blog.posts << Post.new(attributes_of_new_post)
```

And change your has_many to be

```
has_many :posts, :inverse_of => :blog
```

Comment: Interesting. Does `blog.posts << Post.new(attributes_of_new_post)` actually *save* the new Post instance to database?

Comment: Yes.  Either at that moment if blog is already in the DB. Or when you hit blog.save .  Oh those clever rails devs!!!  Surprised me too.

Comment: Those two have the same problem.

Comment: Those two have the same problem. When saving the post you'll get a validating error and when saving or validating the blog you'll get the posts to generating the validation error.

Comment: I updated my answer.   Took me awhile playing around with it.  Most of the time for me the Blog object is already created.

Answer (score 0):

My solution, so far, is to change the validation line from:

```
validates :blog_id, presence: true
```

to

```
validate { errors.add(:blog, "can't be blank") if blog_id.blank? && blog.blank? }
```

which makes me wonder, why isn't Rails doing that for associations? Is there any danger in doing that?